How to get intent by setting AndroidManifest.xml?
I develop a small app with Beeware for android for my own use.
I want to receive intent from other app, like FireFox or Youtube.
I modified AndroidManifest.xml and add
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data
          android:host="www.youtube.com"
          android:scheme="https" />
      <data
          android:host="m.youtube.com"
          android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>

, then build and run , my app isn't on FireFox sharing List.
Something I missing?
i already have send intent to other app, now I want to get intent from  other's to make it better.
--------------------updated-----------------------
i modified my intent-filter,so my app is on Firefox and Youtube sharing List.
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>


Your <intent-filter> is for viewing content, not sharing content.

you are right, i modified my  and , thx.
